# Kafka consumer not picking mentioned Bootstrap servers

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement Kafka consumer with SSL, provide all the required configurations in the application.yml;

When I start the spring boot Kafka consumer application; Consumer is trying to connect the localhost:9092 instead of mentioned Kafka Brokers.

> KafkaConfig.java

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AvroRecord> consumerFactory() throws IOException {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProps());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, AvroRecord>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() throws IOException {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AvroRecord> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

`kafkaProps()` is loading all the SSL and bootstrap servers related properties. Values, I can see it in the debug mode.

> application.yml

```
kafka:
  properties:
    basic:
      auth:
        credentials:
          source: USER_INFO
          user: username
          pass: password
    enableAutoRegister: true
    max_count: 100
    max_delay: 5000
    schema:
      registry:
        url: https://schema-registry:8081
        ssl:
          truststore:
            location: <<location>>
            password: pwd
          keystore:
            location: <<location>>
            password: pwd
          key:
            password: pwd
    ssl:
      enabled: true
      protocols: TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
      truststore:
        type: JKS
        location: <<location>>
        password: pwd
      keystore:
        type: JKS
        location: <<location>>
        password: pwd
      key:
        password: pwd
    security:
      protocol: SSL
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: broker1:9092,broker2:9092
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
      max-message-size: 10241024
```

In the application logs, I am getting the below log

```
18:46:33.964 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.a.AdminClientConfig requestId=
                    transactionKey= | AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000


15:53:54.608 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient requestId=
                    transactionKey= | [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I am not able to find it, why it is connecting to localhost instead of mentioned brokers

Answer (score 1):

1. [The correct property is `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html). You appear to be missing the `spring` prefix completely. Also, `schema.registry.url`, `ssl.truststore`, etc are all considered *singular* property keys (strings) to Kafka clients, so (to my knowledge) therefore should not be "nested" in YAML objects
2. You only tried to set the bootstrap property on the consumer, not the AdminClient
3. Your client will always connect to `advertised.listeners` of the broker after making the initial connection to the bootstrap server string, so if that is `localhost:9092`, would explain the AdminClient log output

Comment: As I am giving the kafka consumer metadata from KafkaConfig class not from application.yml. With spring.kafka.* trusstore location I have to give it as absolute path; So I tried with kafkaConfig

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the consumer and truststore properties don't change my answer. You can still give those along with setting the bootstrap server at the "top level" for all clients rather than only the consumer. You can also create a Factory for the AdminClient